# TinyMCE is blocking only one Polish character

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, polish

TinyMCE works great - look at [example](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/basic-example/).

It works also with characters unique for Polish alphabet, for example: `ąźćńół`.
Except one character:

```
 ę
```

Typing this character in TinyMCE text area do noting (try at [example page](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/basic-example/)). What I should change in configuration file to fix this problem?

Using: TinyMCE 4.3.10.

Comment: Can you try switching to UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I can find such option. There is only https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#entity_encoding which I set to 'raw'. Where is option for character encoding?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I forgot to call you in previous comment. Could you help me?

Comment: Same for "ś" / "Ś"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in the latest version TinyMCE 4.3.11:
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/2870

Thanks.